# How to print the for loop in a class object?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

Hi I am learning about OOP and classes and have some confusion regarding the implementation of classes. Below, I have two sets of identical codes with slight differences in the way I am trying to run them after defining the methods in the class. I am just unsure as to why the first code runs and the second one doesnt as I feel like I am doing the same thing? Also, upon running the first code I get 'None' after the loop has finished, any ideas why that takes place? In addition to this, I know that there are iterators that you can use but just wondering if the method used below to loop through stuff is incorrect or problematic?

```
class i:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number
    def fun(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            print(i)
            
            
kj=i(9)
print(kj.fun())
```

```
class i:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number
    def fun(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            print(i)
            
            
kj=i()
print(kj.fun(9))
```

Comment: `kj.fun()` returns nothing, which is why printing its result gives `None`. You only print things in that function, you never return anything. As far as if it's "correct" to loop the way you're doing, that's impossible to say without more context. And you should just ask one question per post here per the rules anyway.

Comment: Your second snippet is incorrect, because `i.__init__` expects a `number` parameter, but you aren't passing in one when you are instantiating `i()`. It is also incorrect, because you are passing an additional parameter to `kj.fun`, when it doesn't expect to see more than one parameter. Both snippets print `None` at the end, because you are printing the value that is returned by `kj.fun(9)`, which will be `None`, since the `fun` method doesn't return anything explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In python, class names are typically capitalized. This avoids the problem here where you define a class with the same name are your index variable.

Also, if you want to print a result of a method, then have the method return a value rather than having it print each value.

Putting these concepts together, I would change

```
class i:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def fun(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            print(i)
            
            
kj=i(9)
print(kj.fun())
```

to

```
class I:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def fun(self, number=None):
        if not number:
            number = self.number
        return list(range(number))                   
            
kj = I(9)
numbers = kj.fun()

# if you want to print the list
print(numbers)

# if you want to print individual values
print(*numbers)

# if you want to print one number per line
print('\n'.join(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code illustrates the syntax better with type hint:

```
class i:
    def __init__(self,number: int) -> "i":
        self.number=number

    def fun(self) -> None:
        for i in range(self.number):
            print(f"fun - i")
            
            
kj=i(9)
print(kj.fun())
```

The output

```
-> fun - 0
-> fun - 1
-> fun - 2
-> fun - 3
-> fun - 4
-> fun - 5
-> fun - 6
-> fun - 7
-> fun - 8
-> None
```

We see that the output 1 - 8 is from within the function
And None is because the fun() method has None return by default.

The second code will have the following error
`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'`
because to initialise the class it expects the number input. The fact that you want to pass the parameter on the 'fun' method call, it means to expect the number on class initialisation is redundant;

One can do the following instead:

```
class i:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fun(self, number: int):
        for i in range(number):
            print(i)


kj = i()
print(kj.fun(9))
```